# Django objects.all() method return my list in string format (with sqlite)

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-templates

Sorry if my question sounds stupid as i am new to Django.

I have a view in Django like this :

```
def myview(request):

list = Ref.objects.all()

return render_to_response('annonces.html', {'list': list} ,RequestContext(request))
```

Ref is a small sqlite database where i store things scraped from the web.

In my django template, i want to loop on a field of my list object (hurl) which contains a list of links (images) in order to show it on my web page. I've tried this :

```
   {% for value in list %}
       {% for link in value.hurl %}
           <li><img src="{{ link }}"></li>
       {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The object list convert everything to string so the loop in my template create a line for each character in the field hurl.

Would you know how i can get my object to render hurl as a list instead of a string ?

Here is an example of value.hurl :

```
u"['http://3.visuels.poliris.com/thumbnails/3/3/6/5/3365ddc7-3f27.jpg', 'http://1.visuels.poliris.com/thumbnails/1/2/b/6/12b6c286-372f.jpg', 'http://b.visuels.poliris.com/thumbnails/b/4/f/3/b4f32a1c-3159.jpg']"
```

Here is the model. Not sure if URLField is correct for hurl.

```
class Ref(models.Model):

ref = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, primary_key='True')
title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
hurl = models.URLField()
url = models.URLField()
prix = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Thanks
Gilles

Comment: Can you show us what an example value for the `hurl` field?

Comment: I have just added one example :)

Comment: Can you give us Ref model definition?

Comment: That's a string, not a list. So when you iterate over it, you get the what you are seeing now.

Comment: yes that's why i'm asking how i can get a list and not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your object model and store the multiple values for `hurl` as another object.

That object should have a `ForeignKey` to your `Ref`  object:

```
class Ref(models.Model):
    # snip

class Link(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(...)
    ref = models.ForeignKey("Ref")
```

Then, in your template, do:

```
{% for value in list %}
    {% for link in value.link_set %}
        <li><img src="{{ link }}"></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

For better performance, in your view, do:

```
list = Ref.objects.prefetch_related("link_set").all()
```

Comment: Ok Thank you, i'll try and let you know! I will amend my scrappy code and export images in the Link table. It looks like i will have one line per image in the link table then ?

Comment: It works ! I've slightly changed your list though. I have :         {% for link in value.pic_set.all %}
        <li><img src="{{ link.pic }}"></li>. Otherwise, the template fails. Thank you very much for your help